# Missing required parameter slug, laravel 8

Tags: laravel

i have route to get detail data.. but it turns out missing required parameter, i'm using slug as my parameter

Here's my route:

```
 Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'],
    'middleware' => ['setLocale']
], function () {
    Route::get('/our-work', [App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::class, 'index'])->name('project.index');
    Route::get('/our-work/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::class, 'show'])->name('project.show');

});
```

My Controller:

```
public function show($locale, $slug)
    {
        // Get Data Project
        $project = new Client();
        $responseProject = $project->request('GET', env('URL_API') . $locale . '/projects/' . $slug, [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ],
        ]);
        $projects = json_decode($responseProject->getBody(), true);
        $dataProjects = (object) $projects;

        return view('pages.detail', [
            'projects' => $dataProjects->data,
        ]);
    }
```

And here's my href:

```
<a href="{{ route('project.show',['locale'=>app()->getLocale() ,'slug' => $value['project_slug']]) }}">
```

Error:

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: project.show] [URI: {locale}/our-work/{slug}] [Missing parameter: slug].
```

Thankyou

Comment: Is `$value['project_slug']` set, did you check that?

Comment: Yes i do, it's fine, link is good with slug `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/our-work/project-1` .. but when go to detail page, it missing slug as parameter

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted is the code in question? The error message should tell you which file/line the route is wrong

Comment: Sure, all above code is related to the error message for missing parameter..

Comment: Is that `<a href ...` inside a loop or something? If so, are _all_ values set? Do you have a `route` call somewhere in a controller?

Comment: Yes, inside a loop, and all value are set.. for href get the data `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/our-work/project-1` there is no route coll in my controller

Comment: _If_ all values are set as you say (how did you check that?) I don't see how there would be any missing parameter here. Just to be sure, use `dump($value['project_slug'])` before your `<a href` to print it out.

Comment: First the view is the list of the data, so sure all value are set, but when i click one of the list  for detail, error missing parameter but link are good.. i get project-1 when `dump $value['project_slug']`

Comment: So, the error occurs inside the `pages.detail` blade file, which you haven't posted

Comment: My pages.detail blade file is only <h1>Detail Project</h1>, should be no problem..

Comment: You did not explicitly define the type for `slug`. Also, the first parameter should be Request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is from language switcher, need to give params at language

```
<div class="option">
  <a href="{{ route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), ['en', $params]) }}">
     <div onclick="show1('En')">En</div>
  </a>
  <a href="{{ route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), ['id', $params]) }}">
     <div onclick="show1('Bhs')">Bhs</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

And set params value on Controller

```
$params = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{{ route('project.show',['locale'=>app()->getLocale(), $value['project_slug']]) }}">
```

This will work.

Comment: we need to pass paramaterin sequence, not inkey key pair.